# Setting Style TargetType in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a difference between these two ways of setting a style's TargetType?

```
<Style TargetType="Grid"></Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}"></Style>
```

Comment: Check out here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.targettype(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference. You are just explicitly adding the x:Type attribute. By default WPF parses it with {x:Type } that you added in TargetType

EDIT:

When you are using custom controls you want to explitly set the {x:Type CustomControl}

Comment: Are there cases when you would prefer one or the other?

Comment: @PatrickY Here is the documentation on the `x:Type` markup extension http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If it's for custom controls, why do I frequently see {x:Type ..} used for standard WPF controls, like Grid?

Comment: @PatrickY it's probably just like the `private` keyword for class members -- that's the default, so you don't need it, but some people prefer to see it there explicitly.